# Why am I getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'BuyToken' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

I want to buy a token in the contract, but every time a run test class, it has not worked.

I wrote this contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import "./Token.sol";

contract KIA is Token {
    Token private token;

    constructor(
        address owner,
        uint256 initSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol,
        uint8 decimalUnits
    ) Token(owner, initSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol, decimalUnits) {}

    function ownerToken() external view returns (address) {
        return token.owner();
    }

    function BuyToken(uint256 rate) external payable {
        uint256 tokenAmount = msg.value * rate;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokenAmount);
    }
}
```

and this contract inheritance from Token:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

import "./SafeMath.sol";

contract Token is SafeMath {
    uint256 public totalToken;
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint256 public decimals;
    address tokenOwner;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balance;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowed;

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    constructor(
        address owner,
        uint256 initSupply,
        string memory tokenName,
        string memory tokenSymbol,
        uint8 decimalUnits
    ) {
        balance[owner] = initSupply;
        totalToken = initSupply;
        name = tokenName;
        symbol = tokenSymbol;
        decimals = decimalUnits;
        tokenOwner = owner;
    }

    //
    modifier transferFromModifire(
        address _to,
        address _from,
        uint256 _value
    ) {
        require(_value <= 0, " value can not be 0  ");
        require(balance[_from] < _value, " not have enough money ");
        require(balance[_to] + _value < balance[_to], " overflow Error ");
        require(
            _value > allowed[_from][msg.sender],
            " i dont know whats error "
        );
        _;
    }

    modifier transferModifire(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require(_value <= 0);
        require(balance[_to] + _value < balance[_to]);
        _;
    }

    // Send Owner Address
    function owner() external view returns(address) {
        return tokenOwner;
    }

    // Send Token From Owner To Address
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)
        external
        transferModifire(_to, _value)
        returns (bool)
    {
        balance[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balance[msg.sender], _value);
        balance[_to] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balance[_to], _value);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    // Send Token From Address To Address
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) external transferFromModifire(_to, _from, _value) returns (bool) {
        balance[_from] = SafeMath.safeSub(balance[msg.sender], _value);
        balance[_to] = SafeMath.safeAdd(balance[_to], _value);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to test and deploy contract:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { AbiItem } from 'web3-utils';
import * as KiaToken from '../build/KIA.json';


const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/afa51bf9aa97452d90cbc4713d14888d');


describe("Kiaswap Contract", () => {

    let rapstoneAddress = '0xB643992c9fBcb1Cb06b6C9eb278b2ac35e6a2711';
    let initSupply = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
    let TokenName = 'KIA';
    let tokenSymbol = 'LION';
    let decimalUnits = 8;
    let token: any;

    beforeEach(async () => {

        token = await new web3.eth.Contract(KiaToken.abi as AbiItem[])
            .deploy({
                data: KiaToken.evm.bytecode.object,
                arguments: [rapstoneAddress, initSupply, TokenName, tokenSymbol, decimalUnits]
            });
    })


    it('Owner ', async () => {
      let owner =   await token.methods.BuyToken().call();
      assert.equal(rapstoneAddress,owner);
    })
})
```

but after I run this code:

```
 it('Owner ', async () => {
      let owner =   await token.methods.BuyToken().call();
      assert.equal(rapstoneAddress,owner);
    })
```

it show me error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'BuyToken' of undefined

Now whats the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Are you able to test Token.sol with Remix IDE? I think there are several issues.
A) In place of:

```
contract Token is SafeMath {
```

It should be:

```
contract Token {
using SafeMath  for uint256;
```

because you don't want to use inheritance but just want to use SafeMath functions.

B) Function "function owner()" should be renamed to "function getTokenOwner()".

C) Maybe there is something wrong with your SafeMath. I think these libraries could be very popular:
https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/master/contracts/libraries/SafeMath.sol
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol
I was expecting in place of:

```
balance[msg.sender] = SafeMath.safeSub(balance[msg.sender], _value);
```

it should be:

```
balance[msg.sender] = balance[msg.sender].sub(_value);
```

Maybe there is something more but I noticed above issues quite fast... I googled a little bit and [this code looks very similar to yours](https://forum.ivanontech.com/t/first-project-erc20-contract/34471). May that solves the issue?

Comment: hi tanks for answer my question . I changed my code to every thing you told . bit still have a problem and show me that error